# How to do a mutation to made a change in local cache Apollo v3?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Let's suppose we have such a schema on the client.

```
 const typeDefs = gql`
   type System {
      showSignInModal: Boolean!
      menuPermanent: Boolean!
      isLogged: Boolean!
      accessToken: String
      themeMode: String
    }
  `;
```

How can we create a mutation to change the *menuPermanent* value to `true`? < br />
In Apollo v3 local field resolvers had been deprecated so now we can't do the standard @client mutation.

In the Apollo v3 documentation, I saw they suggest to use direct `client.writeQuery` or `client.writeFragment` methods but I don't understand clearly how can they be used. Does it mean we don't need to create a Mutation to change the cache but rather import the **client** Instance or receive it by using **useApolloClient** hook and execute the `writeQuery` method directly on it?

Reactive variables are nice but I'm interested in the same way for all app parts. Either server or client. Previously both of them used Mutations but now I'm a bit confused with all of these major changes so I'd really like to know how can we use Mutations in the case of Apollo v3 to update the local cache state property.

Apollo client initialization

```
 const typeDefs = gql`
   type System {
      showSignInModal: Boolean!
      menuPermanent: Boolean!
      isLogged: Boolean!
      accessToken: String
      themeMode: String
    }
  `;

export let cache = new InMemoryCache();

// SET THE INITIAL LOCAL CACHE STATE
cache.writeQuery({
  query: GET_SYSTEM_DATA,
  data: {
    system: {
      showSignInModal: false,
      menuPermanent: false,
      isLogged: false,
      accessToken: null,
      themeMode: 'white'
    }
  }
});

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://nextjs-graphql-with-prisma-simple.vercel.app/api', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
    }),
    typeDefs,
    cache: cache
  })
}
```

The component where I'm trying to change the cache value

```
import { gql, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';


const B = () => {

  const client = useApolloClient();
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Test Query Component B</span>
      <button onClick={() => {
        client.writeFragment({
          fragment: gql`
          fragment MySystem on System {
            menuPermanent
          }
        `,
        data: {
          system: { menuPermanent: true, }
        },
        })
      }} >Set menu permanent</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But it doesn't change the local cache at all.

Thanks for any help or info.

Comment: why fragment? use writeQuery? .... deprecated doesn't mean removed

Comment: Because deprecated things will be removed anyway, soon or later so I'd like to migrate to the latest version :)